# How to address, delete or access child objects in ElasticSearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

How are child objects addressed in elasticseacrch?

Suppose we create two parents and three children. Note that there are two
children with id `c2` but with different parents:

```
curl -XPUT localhost:9200/test/parent/p1 -d'{
  "name": "Parent 1"
}'

curl -XPUT localhost:9200/test/parent/p2 -d'{
  "name": "Parent 2"
}'

curl -XPOST localhost:9200/test/child/_mapping -d '{
  "child":{
    "_parent": {"type": "parent"}
  }
}'

curl -XPOST localhost:9200/test/child/c1?parent=p1 -d '{
   "child": "Parent 1 - Child 1"
}'

curl -XPOST localhost:9200/test/child/c2?parent=p1 -d '{
   "child": "Parent 1 - Child 2"
}'

curl -XPOST localhost:9200/test/child/c2?parent=p2 -d '{
   "child": "Parent 2 - Child 2"
}'
```

If we search the children, we see that there are two children with `_id` of `c2`

```
curl -XGET localhost:9200/test/_search

{
  "_shards": {
    "failed": 0, 
    "successful": 5, 
    "total": 5
  }, 
  "hits": {
    "hits": [
      {
        "_id": "c1", 
        "_index": "test", 
        "_score": 1.0, 
        "_source": {
          "child": "Parent 1 - Child 1"
        }, 
        "_type": "child"
      }, 
      {
        "_id": "c2", 
        "_index": "test", 
        "_score": 1.0, 
        "_source": {
          "child": "Parent 1 - Child 2"
        }, 
        "_type": "child"
      }, 
      {
        "_id": "c2", 
        "_index": "test", 
        "_score": 1.0, 
        "_source": {
          "child": "Parent 2 - Child 2"
        }, 
        "_type": "child"
      }
    ], 
    "max_score": 1.0, 
    "total": 3
  }, 
  "timed_out": false, 
  "took": 1
}
```

How do I address `p1/c2`? Without the parent child relationship, the `_id` can be used access, change or delete a child object. In my case I let elasticsearch create the `id` of the objects.

To access the child objects, the `_id` is not enough:

```
curl -XGET localhost:9200/test/child/c2
```

I have to specify the parent as well:

```
curl -XGET localhost:9200/test/child/c2?parent=p1
```

In my system it is worse, some objects I can directly access without the `parent` and others I cannot access. (Why???)

If I delete c2 (without parent!):

```
curl -XDELETE http://localhost:9200/test/child/c2
```

both children are deleted. To delete only one child I have to use `?parent=p1`

```
curl -XDELETE http://localhost:9200/test/child/c2?parent=p1
```

Here are my questions.

- **What is the best practices to manage the identity of child objects?**
- Does that mean, that I have to somehow put the parent id manually into the child object and then construct the of the object as `id?parent=parent_id`
- Why does elasticsearch not return the parent id?
- If I let elasticseach create the id of the child objects, are they guaranteed to be unique or can it happen that two children of different parents get the same `id`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Child documents are just ordinary documents in Elasticsearch, with an additional _parent field that points to a document in the parent type.
When accessing child documents, either when indexing or when getting, you need to specify the parent id in the request. This is because the parent id is actually used for routing of the child document (see for instance about routing -http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search.html#search-routing).
This means that the child document is sharded according to the **parent** id, so it resides on the same shard as the parent.

In your example above, what probably happened is that each of your c2 documents was created on a separate shard - one was sharded by its own id, and the other (where you specified the parent) according to the parent id.

This is important to understand so you won't have inconsistencies between index, get and search. So you need to remember to **always** pass the parent when you're working with child documents so they will be routed to the right shard.

About the document id - you need to treat it like all other documents. This means that it needs to be unique, you can't have 2 documents with the same id even if they have different parents.
You can either use the parent id as part of the child document id (as you suggested), or let ES generate a unique id if that makes sense in your use case. Document IDs that ES generates are unique, no matter the parent.

About getting the parent field back, you need to request it explicitly, it is not returned by default. (Request it using the fields parameter - http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-get.html#get-fields, or in search - https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-stored-fields.html).