# How to automatically delete all of the children documents in ElasticSearch after the parent is deleted?

Tags: elasticsearch

When the users upload a file or create a folder, I add a corresponding document into the *ElasticSearch*, **what I'm trying to do**, is to delete the all the corresponding documents after the users delete a folder, which means I need to delete the folder's document and all of its subfolder or file' documents, how can I get it done?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to address, delete or access child objects in ElasticSearch?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19862634/how-to-address-delete-or-access-child-objects-in-elasticsearch)